# Pronunciation of tissue

Tags: pronunciation, palatalization, yod-coalescence

I have heard two pronunciations for the word tissue. Tishoo and Tisyou.

Tishoo is of course the one in common use but what is the current status on Tisyou ?

It ''feels'' like an archaic way of pronouncing tissue but that might not be true.

It also ''feels'' more British and more formal.

I found myself using Tishoo for paper and Tisyou for organic tissue. As in skin tissue.

What is the status/useage of the tisyou pronunciation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The strange pronunciations of "assume"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553132/the-strange-pronunciations-of-assume) //// it was pronounced *Tis-you* in RP but the /s/ and /j/ ('y') got assimilated to *sh*, yielding *tishoo*..... Also see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/564912)

Comment: There are good articles on the internet; [this Youtube/SpeechModification.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEHjc4jEK5A) treatment is very clear.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That video doesn't mention *ti**s** you* though.

Comment: I voted to close because of lack of signs of research, not because I think this is a duplicate.